# Resolution issue

Tags: resolution

My harddrive crashed and I recently got a new one and re-installed Windows XP.  When I am in windows, it will not allow me to change the resolution to anything other than 640x480.  I think that it doesn't recognize the monitor properly as in the window where the resolution can be changed it only says Default Monitor and not a particular one.  Any suggestions on how to get it to recognize my monitor?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that Windows is defaulting to the "Default VGA Adapter".

If I was you, go to either the [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com) or [ATI](http://www.ati.com) website and download the latest drivers. (or [Intel](http://www.intel.com) / [Via](http://www.via.com.tw) / other if you have that instead).

Once installed, you should be able to select the correct resolution.

Comment: If it's a notebook computer, you might want to check on the notebook maker's site for drivers instead of the graphic card maker's website.

Answer (score 1):

I got into exactly the same issue, a week back. I was re-installing on a Dell laptop. Basic Windows XP installation was allowing only 640x480 resolution. So I took another CD provided by Dell, and installed some of the drivers on it (the Dell software detected the HW and associated drivers). So if you have vendor's CD, then try it. Otherwise, use device manager to note the video card you have, and download it directly from internet.